# Как подставить номер элемента из массива строго попорядку Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как подставить номер элемента строго попорядку в атрибут data-slide-to. Если фото несколько, например, 5, то в атрибут подставлялся номер от 0 (не использую id строчки из БД).

```html
@foreach($images as $im)
<li data-target="#carouselCaptions" data-slide-to="{{ $im->id }}" class=""></li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто используем $key

```
    @foreach($images as $key => $im)
<li data-target="#carouselCaptions" data-slide-to="{{ $key }}" class=""></li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

При итерации в blade появляется дополнительная переменная `$loop` ([подробнее](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable)), потому можно сделать, например, так:

```
@foreach($images as $im)
<li data-target="#carouselCaptions" data-slide-to="{{ $loop->index }}" class=""></li>
@endforeach
```